# mongodb update all document with incrementing the value by 1

Tags: mongodb

i have several document in mongoDB, doc structure is like this

```
{
"a":"abc",
"myid":2
}
```

I want to update "myid" of all document with 1. for example for 1st document myid = 1, for second document myid =2 and so on. Is there a query?

Comment: please check the answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Try this query:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
 {},
 {$inc:{myid:1}}
)
```

Answer (score -5):

Create a separate Collection called Counter to track the last sequence number.

```
    db.counters.insert(
    {
        _id: "userid",
        seq: 0
    });
```

And create a function to fetch seq value for Counter collection.

```
function getNextSequence(name) {
      var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
      {
        query: { _id: name },
        update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
        new: true
      });
      return ret.seq;
}
```

And Increment your auto-increment field like below.

```
db.collection.insert({
   "a":"abc",
   "myid": getNextSequence("userid")
});
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This is not a noSQL way of doing things. This operation can be performed atomically as indicated in the accepted answer. You also aren't actually answering the op's question. Your answer is if they wanted to create a new document with an incremented number based on existing documents. In that case, it would be much more performant to perform a count operation (potentially on an indexed field if it needs to be filtered) and increment the results of the count to apply to the new document. Your solution is a non performant and overly complex way to do things in mongodb. No disrespect intended