# MongoQuery to update document using addition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document in student collection:

```
{
"uid": 1,
"eng": 70
}
```

Now I want to add 10 into eng field and want result 80. to do this I am using following query:

```
db.getCollection('student').aggregate([{$match:{uid:1}},{$set:{eng:{$sum:10}}}])
```

but it is not working. SO how can add any number in the field to the required output? is any addition query in MongoDB. help me here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongodb update all document with incrementing the value by 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49584703/mongodb-update-all-document-with-incrementing-the-value-by-1) there are so many similar questions, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172755/increment-value-in-mongodb

Comment: @Suraj Dalvi: JFYI, `.aggregate()` is used for `reads` but not for `writes`, there are only two stages in `.aggregate()` that will write to DB (`$out` & `$merge`)..You're combining `.aggregate()` stages with `crud operations`, check this : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION #1**: Set sum to the same field `eng`.

```js
db.student.aggregate([
    { $match: { uid: 1 } },
    {
        $set: {
            eng: { $add: ["$eng", 10] }        // $sum: ["$eng", 10] Also works;)
        }
    }
])
```

Output:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6065f94abb72032a689ed61d"),
    "uid" : 1,
    "eng" : 80
}
```

**SOLUTION #2**: Set sum to a different field `result`.

1. Using [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) add `result` filed.
2. Using [$add](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) add 10 to `eng` and store it in `result`.

```js
db.student.aggregate([
    { $match: { uid: 1 } }, 
    { 
        $addFields: { 
            result: { $add: ["$eng", 10] }    
        } 
    }
])
```

Output:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6065f94abb72032a689ed61d"),
    "uid" : 1,
    "eng" : 70,
    "result" : 80
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the `$inc` operator here:

```
db.getCollection('student').update(
    { uid: 1 },
    { $inc: { eng: 10 } }
)
```